# How to prevent scrolling to focused EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-scrollview

Android scrolls to the focused EditText inside a ScrollView when the activity gains focus.

How can I tell Android NOT to do this but instead maintain scroll position?

The situation:

A validation method must scroll to a TextView for the user's attention. It sets focus to an EditText outside the viewable area to avoid user confusion (which happens when Android sets focus on the closest but unrelated EditText after scrolling down).

The user clicks a button and enters data in a second activity via startActivityForResult. onActivityResult renders the result in the same TextView. Now the TextView is no longer visible because Android scrolls to the focused EditText.

Comment: Thanks, yes, is duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Try `setSelected(false)` for the EditText.

Comment: Thanks. No difference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the EditText one can use another View to steal the focus e.g. layout with attributes android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true". Android does not seem to use this to scroll ScrollView which is exactly what I need. It's a hack and discouraged but my 1st attempt is a hack too, to work around a bug so who cares :). Thanks matthias for the hint.